# Simple Q regarding MySQL inline UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a little confusion in this issue... For the same reason we use transactions and before applying our logic and updating a row in database we of course SELECT it with LOCK IN SHARE MODE.

However my question is, if there is an inline update query for numeric value: i.e:

```
UPDATE table SET num1=num1+1, num2=num2-1 WHERE group='abc'
```

Will this provide always accurate value without locking row / using transactions?
and what if this query is used along side other logic in a transaction (which is "required" for some other query).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will, because everything done in InnoDB is in a transaction, always.  If you don't start the transaction yourself, InnoDB starts it for you, and the transaction lasts for exactly one statement.  Row operations are always atomic.

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Incidentally, though, based on thr rest of the question... when you know you are going to update a row, you should `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and go ahead and take the exclusive lock explicitly now, rather than implicitly, later.  A shared mode lock is intended to prevent other rows from obtaining exclusive locks and has to be escalated before you can modify the row, somewhat increasing the likelihood of deadlocks.